# Error installing pyosc, invalid syntax on: binary = struct.pack('>ll', 0L, 1L)

Tags: python, osc

I am trying install pyosc-0.3.5b-5294 for my Anoconda python (3.5). I am running it on Win10. 
I got the syntax error when I ran python setup.py install

File "C:\Users\eric1\Downloads\pyOSC-0.3.5b-5294\OSC.py", line 735
    binary = struct.pack('>ll', 0L, 1L)
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

any intuition of fixing the problem? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, my intuition tells me that that module is written for Python 2, for which `0L` is valid syntax for a long integer literal, rather than Python 3, for which it is not.

Comment: yeah. It is for python2. Unfortunately I dont seem to find a Python3 version of pyosc.

Comment: Then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

pyOSC only works in Python 2 and is not maintained, I think the best solution is to try a different OSC library: e.g., [python-osc](https://github.com/attwad/python-osc) works in Python 3.